# Show that if a is a positive constant, then x = 0 is the only critical point of f(x) = x + a √ x.

Tags: calculus

Okay. So I've plugged in a positive constant (2) to see what happens when you take the derivative. Always gets me some variant of root x in the denominator, and giving me no critical points, rather than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $f'>0 \quad \forall x>0$, so there is no critical point by definition. We also know $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. Hence $x=0$ is a local minimum. Thus it must be a critical point (even if $f$'s not differentiable).

I am not sure whether this is the answer you are looking for since I don't know what's your definition of critical point. But based on what I learnt, [critical point](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) is only defined when $f$ is differentiable.